# Unable to login to Careers.StackOverflow with OpenID

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, stack-exchange-openid

Whenever I access careers.stackoverflow.com, I get prompted to log in. I choose the StackExchange Open ID, but it comes up with `unexpected error encountered`. Tried different browsers, and different machines (different IP's).

Comment: We are aware of an issue and are working on it, thanks.

Comment: thanks for the update.

Comment: This should be resolved now.

Comment: [yay](http://derpy.ponychan.net/chan/files/src/134205831823.png)

Comment: @ajax thats amazing